# Understanding partition size on /proc/partitions

Tags: partitions

I am trying to build a LineageOS ROM for an unsupported device. I need to get the partition size of the device. I have a rooted device and then went to `/proc/partitions` via root explorer, and I have like:

```
major minor    #blocks name

    7     0      65536 loop0
    7     1      98304 loop1
  179     0  122138624 mmcblk0
  179     1      16384 mmcblk0p1
  179     2      16384 mmcblk0p2
  179     3      16384 mmcblk0p3
  179     4       4096 mmcblk0p4
  179     5      16384 mmcblk0p5
  179     6      16384 mmcblk0p6
  179     7       2048 mmcblk0p7
  179     8       1024 mmcblk0p8
  179     9       1024 mmcblk0p9
  179    10      40960 mmcblk0p10
  179    11       8192 mmcblk0p11
  179    12      32768 mmcblk0p12
  179    13       8192 mmcblk0p13
  179    14      65536 mmcblk0p14
  179    15     262144 mmcblk0p15
  259     0     307200 mmcblk0p16
  259     1      32768 mmcblk0p17
  259     2    2359296 mmcblk0p18
  259     3  118931419 mmcblk0p19
  179    48       4096 mmcblk0rpmb
  179    32       4096 mmcblk0boot1
  179    16       4096 mmcblk0boot0
  179    64    7761920 mmcblk1li
  179    65    7757824 mmcblk1p1
```

I want to know under which format these block sizes are. Whether they are in bytes, Kb or Mb?

As I know, `mmcblk0p1` is the boot partition and its block size is 16384, so what it will be in bytes?

Comment: Yeah the sizes are in bytes

Comment: @esQmo_ Do proper math? 16384B is just 16KB. // To OP: from my (admittedly shallow) Linux knowledge, reported block size is always 512 bytes. That gives 8MB for `mmcblk0p1`, and ~58GB for `mmcblk0` (the entire eMMC). Is your device 64GB? If yes this would be the reasonable amount.

Comment: I have doubt as 1 MB is almost equals to 1048576, then it means here boot partition is of 0.016384 MB

Comment: @AndyYan i have an 128gb device

Comment: @Andy Yan The size is indeed 16 mb as 16384kb. Should've I just said approximately 17mb :p

Comment: @Rahul Sharma what device is it?

Comment: Besides, this looks like a MMC partition layout as they are read from `/proc/partitions`; eMMC's are read from `/proc/emmc` (I may be wrong thought)

Comment: @esQmo_ i have Asus Zenfone Zoom

Comment: As your device is rooted, you can install `parted` utility with ADB shell which will give you the sizes in MB instead

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151493/discussion-on-question-by-rahul-sharma-understanding-partition-size-on-proc-par); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.